# Classic ASP & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, layer

Can anyone help me on my query. I have a page which has a button

```
<button id="btnStudents" name="btnStudents" style="width:90px;cursor:default;" title="Click to add/update/delete Student records" onClick="javascript:fn_ShowHide('lyrStudents', this.id)"> 
                <table width="100%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
                  <tr> 
                    <td height="25"> 
                      <div align="center"><img src="../images/icons/student.gif" hspace="0" align="absmiddle" width="32" height="32" vspace="10"><font class="BodyHDRFontBold"></font></div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr> 
                    <td height="25"> 
                      <div align="center"> <font class="BodyHDRFontBold"><b>Manage 
                        Students</b></font></div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                </button>
```

and whenever this button is clicked, a small layer should open right under the button. I tried to do it using button's left and top but it did not work in all the browsers.
Layer code is below. Layer by default will be hidden unless user clicks on the button.

```
                    <div id="lyrStudents" style="position:absolute; left:749px; top:412px; width:183px; height:148px; z-index:1; background-color: #FFFFFF; layer-background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px none #000000;"> 
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tblBorder">
                    <tr> 
                      <td colspan="2" class="bgColorBar" height="25"> 
                        <div align="center"><font class="BodyFontNormal"><b>:: 
                          Students Menu ::</b></font></div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td colspan="2"><img src="../images/supporting/b3b3ff_line.png" width="100%" height="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td width="88%">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td width="88%">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td width="88%">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Where is the classic ASP? Where is the JavaScript? Not to mention that the HTML looks like it came out of 1998.

Comment: Hi raynos, I did not understand your comments on Where is the Classic ASP and JavaScript..??

Comment: @Yashman Raynos and also I cannot see your javascript and asp classic source code in your post. You tagged your question in this catogories without any connection to those.

Comment: @YashmanGupta yes. You forgot to paste your javascript and your asp in the question. All I see is HTML

Comment: Hi raynos & reporter, I am asking for JavaScript. The JavaScript which I wrote did not work that is why I have not posted in it. As for the ASP Code, the button is created using standard HTML on an ASP page which has other parts dynamic

Comment: I don't think you understand how Stack Overflow works. This website is for discussing specific issues and topics related to programming; it is not a website to request others to write code for you.

Comment: function fn_GetPos()
{
 var intLeft, intTop, intButtonHeight;
 
 intButtonHeight = (document.getElementById("btnStudents").style.clientHeight) + 50;
 
 intTop = document.getElementById("btnStudents").style.offsetTop;
 intLeft = document.getElementById("btnStudents").style.offsetLeft;
 
 document.getElementById("lyrStudents").style.left = intLeft;
 document.getElementById("lyrStudents").style.top = intTop + intButtonHeight;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your direct / indirect help. I have managed to get the issue resolved from external sources.

```
function fn_Reposition(strFieldName, lyrName )
{
var intLeft, intTop, intBtnHeight, obj;

obj = document.getElementById(strFieldName);
intBtnHeight = document.getElementById(strFieldName).clientHeight;

document.getElementById(lyrName).style.top = getElTop(obj) + intBtnHeight;
document.getElementById(lyrName).style.left = getElLeft(obj)
}


// Many thanks to Paul Hayman 
// Code Source: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/ViewContent.aspx?ContentID=252 
function getElLeft(el)
{
if (ns4)
{
    return el.pageX;
} 
else
{
    xPos = el.offsetLeft;
    tempEl = el.offsetParent;
    while (tempEl != null)
    {
        xPos += tempEl.offsetLeft;
        tempEl = tempEl.offsetParent;
    }
    return xPos;
}
}
function getElTop(el)
{
if (ns4)
{
    return el.pageY;
} 
else
{
    yPos = el.offsetTop;
    tempEl = el.offsetParent;
    while (tempEl != null)
    {
        yPos += tempEl.offsetTop;
        tempEl = tempEl.offsetParent;
    }
    return yPos;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just done something similar. Hope you can use this. It uses [prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/) and [scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/):

```
      function hideDivs() {
    Element.hide('subnavHM');
    $('subnavHM').shown = false;

    Element.hide('subnavSS');
    $('subnavSS').shown = false;

    Element.hide('subnavPO');
    $('subnavPO').shown = false;

    Element.hide('subnavIN');
    $('subnavIN').shown = false;

    Element.hide('subnavPE');
    $('subnavPE').shown = false;

    Element.hide('subnavAN');
    $('subnavAN').shown = false;

    Element.hide('subnavDV');
    $('subnavDV').shown = false;

  }

  function showHide(div) {
    hideDivs();

    if ($(div).shown) {
      $(div).style.visibility = "hidden";
      new Effect.Fade($(div));
      $(div).shown = false;

    }
    else {
      $(div).style.visibility = "visible";
      new Effect.Appear($(div));
      $(div).shown = true;
    }
  }
```

I run hideDivs from body onload

Comment: At least link MooTools in :( and that code is horrible. Really horrible.

Comment: @Raynos If it was mootools... I use prototype.js, which I wrote.